# Terminal is not opening from GUI in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, shortcut-keys

I accidentally deleted python from the lib folder, because I saw multiple versions of python.

1. Initially, the GUI was not loading, the only terminal was working then I upgrade with the command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
   ```

   After that, I can access GUI but from GUI I am not able to access terminal.
2. I have tried all shortcut options and also tried clicking on the terminal icon, but the terminal is not opening.

   But, when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3 or F4</kbd>, I moved on terminal and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for GUI.

Please help me out here, so that I can open the terminal as a normal way from the GUI.

Comment: You've tagged 14.04, but say 18.04 in the heading?.  Two pythons should be there; `python` & `python3` and the way they are used varies in 14.04 & 18.04. If you enter `python -V ; python3 -V` what do you get as responses?  (switch to text terminal; ctrl+alt+F4 if needs be)

Comment: @guiverc, I have not seen 18.04 in tag that's why I added 14.04
[`$ python -V = 2.7.15+`]
[`$ python3 -V = 3.6.8`]

Comment: You should have got two responses, you also didn't clarify the 14.04 & 18.04 difference.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is off-topic due to EOL status, Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is off-topic as all ESM releases are;   so by your tagged release you're off-topic (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @guiverc I updated tag

Comment: You've don't appear to have the correct result for `python3` for 18.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=python3) which means many of the builtin system tools may not work, and a restore of data is fastest ... I'd look at `history`  for clues on your installing a different `python3` and reverse that; as many package tools also may not work...  (to me it looks like a wrong version, plus you've acknowledged deleting part of it so I'm not sure `apt` tools would be reliable..)  *Others here may know more, but I'd `cp` from backups/another box/build*